# Acura smoking and shaking

Tags: acura

I have a 96 Acura, my son was driving 700 miles. last hour or two of the trip he said the car started shaking. few hours later he said it started smoking under the hood and he opened the hood and seen a spark /small fire and liquid, pulled water on it and started smoking quite a bit. The crazy thing is , the car will still start but not sure how safe it is. Any suggestions

Comment: I see the [tag:318i] on this question but you've mentioned an Acura above.  That doesn't seem to fit since the 318i is a BMW.

Comment: For clarity, is this an on-going situation?  Is the car on fire right now (26 September 2016)?  I suspect that the answers will tend to focus on "this doesn't sound safe at all."